# How to get raw data of http post request inn Golang using gin framework

Tags: http, go, post, raw

I am getting one POST request in my server whose payload is something like that

```
{       "amount": 10000,
        "amount_due": 0,
        "amount_paid": 10000,
        "attempts": 1,
}
```

and content-type is application/json.
Now for some calculation I want that payload in raw text something like that.

```
{"amount":10000,"amount_due":0,"amount_paid":10000,"attempts":1} 
No space and no new line
```

I am using Golang and gin framework, but which I am trying to get the request body like
ginCtx *gin.Context.Request.Body or ginCtx *gin.Context.GetRawData(), then I am not getting my actual desired raw data, I am getting well indented json, but I want raw body.
Please help me how to get that in Golang using gin framework.

Answer (score 2):

> but I want raw body

Note that **raw** means unprocessed, which is exactly what [`c.GetRawData()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.GetRawData) returns.

If you want to take the raw data and remove all insignificant whitespace then you need to process the data. The result of that processing, by definition, will not be **raw data** anymore.

So it is not very clear what you are asking for.

- Do you want raw data? Then use [`c.GetRawData()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.GetRawData).
- Do you want data with insignificant whitespace removed? Then use [`json.Compact`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Compact).

```golang
raw, err := c.GetRawData()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
var buf bytes.Buffer
if err := json.Compact(&buf, raw); err != nil {
    return err
}
data := buf.Bytes()
fmt.Println(string(data))
```